# The NavigationItem's TintColor can not be set

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

### My Situation:

- There are a View_A (`UICollectionViewController`&`UICollectionViewCell`) and View_B (`UIViewController`). I want to switch to the View_B when I touched one of cell in the View_A with `Segue` in the `StoryBoard`.
- In the `StoryBoard`, I connected View_A and View_B with the `Push Segue` which identifier is `SegueToView_B`.
- And the function of switchViews just worked fine.

### My Problem:

- With the `Push Segue`, I do not need to add a BackButton (`NavigationItem`) to turn back to the View_A, because there is a 'NavigationItem' be crated  automatically by system. And I tried other type segues, like `Modal`, `Popover`, and the `NavigationItem` was not created automatically. I want to ask why?
- I want to set the specific color, not the default blue, for that `NavigationItem` which be created by system automatically, but I failed to find it. After that I just set the color in the `prepareForSegue()`, but it did not work. Please tell how to set the specific color for it?

### My Code:

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.collectionView?.setPresenting(true, animated: true, completion: nil)
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    self.selectedCard = delegate.otherCards[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToView_B", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "SegueToView_B" {
            let myOtherCardViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? View_BViewController
            myOtherCardViewController!.otherCard = self.selectedCard
            myOtherCardViewController!.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  // Failed to work!!!
            myOtherCardViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  // Failed to work, too!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Ethan Joe

Comment: Step 1.: Stop to use `?` if something has to happen. Maybe `backBarButtonItem` and `leftBarButtonItem` are nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the `tintColor` for that navigation bar:

```
myOtherCardViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = .whiteColor()
```

Why there is no Navigationbar when you use the Modal or PopOver? Because thats how Modal and Popover work! You have to create another Navigation controller for the view you are connecting with the Modal segue, like this:
[image]

Another technique I am using is, to create a single NavigationController class, and set all the desired properties (color, font etc.) and then link all the NavigationControllers in the Storyboard to that NavigationController class.

With that you wont have to reconfigure every NavigationController.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is very clear and useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Solution**

- You can set back button hidden in View_B controller in `viewDidLoad` method like this.

  ```
  class View_BViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
          self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      } 
  }
  ```
- To set tint color, you have to create subclass of `UINavigationController`, and assign that class to your UINavigationController in `UIStoryboard`

You subclass will look like this, to set tint color,

```
class navigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //Other stuff
}
```

May this help you!!

Comment: I used the other way to solve it. But still thanks for your answer.